# Can't build project Sagan with gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I am trying to run Spring's [project Sagan](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan) locally. As instructed in the project wiki I tried to build it with gradle. But fails with this test error:

```
    java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: "{\n  \"from\" : 0,\n  \"size\" : 10,\n  \"query\" : {\n    \"filtered\" : {\n      \"query\" : {\n        \"bool\" : {\n          \"must\" : {\n            \"multi_match\" : {\n              \"query\" : \"spring boot\",\n              \"fields\" : [ \"title^3\", \"rawContent\", \"author\" ],\n              \"fuzziness\" : 1,\n              \"minimum_should_match\" : \"30%\"\n            }\n          },\n          \"should\" : [ {\n            \"term\" : {\n              \"current\" : true\n            }\n          }, {\n            \"term\" : {\n              \"_type\" : \"projectpage\"\n            }\n          }, {\n            \"match\" : {\n              \"title\" : {\n                \"query\" : \"spring boot\",\n                \"type\" : \"phrase\",\n                \"boost\" : 3.0,\n                \"slop\" : 1\n              }\n            }\n          } ]\n        }\n      },\n      \"filter\" : {\n        \"or\" : {\n          \"filters\" : [ {\n            \"range\" : {\n              \"publishAt\" : {\n                \"from\" : null,\n                \"to\" : \"now/d\",\n                \"include_lower\" : true,\n                \"include_upper\" : true\n              }\n            }\n          }, {\n            \"not\" : {\n              \"filter\" : {\n                \"type\" : {\n                  \"value\" : \"blogpost\"\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          } ]\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  },\n  \"post_filter\" : {\n    \"or\" : {\n      \"filters\" : [ {\n        \"and\" : {\n          \"filters\" : [ {\n            \"terms\" : {\n              \"facetPaths\" : [ \"Projects/Api\", \"Projects/Reference\" ],\n              \"execution\" : \"or\"\n            }\n          }, {\n            \"terms\" : {\n              \"facetPaths\" : [ \"Projects/Reactor Project/1.1.0.RELEASE\" ],\n              \"execution\" : \"or\"\n            }\n          } ]\n        }\n      }, {\n        \"terms\" : {\n          \"facetPaths\" : [ \"Blog/Engineering\" ],\n          \"execution\" : \"or\"\n        }\n      } ]\n    }\n  },\n  \"sort\" : [ {\n    \"_score\" : { }\n  }, {\n    \"publishAt\" : {\n      \"order\" : \"desc\"\n    }\n  } ],\n  \"facets\" : {\n    \"facet_paths_result\" : {\n      \"terms\" : {\n        \"field\" : \"facetPaths\",\n        \"size\" : 100000,\n        \"order\" : \"term\"\n      }\n    }\n  },\n  \"highlight\" : {\n    \"order\" : \"score\",\n    \"require_field_match\" : false,\n    \"fields\" : {\n      \"rawContent\" : {\n        \"fragment_size\" : 300,\n        \"number_of_fragments\" : 1\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}"
     but: was "{\r\n  \"from\" : 0,\r\n  \"size\" : 10,\r\n  \"query\" : {\r\n    \"filtered\" : {\r\n      \"query\" : {\r\n        \"bool\" : {\r\n          \"must\" : {\r\n            \"multi_match\" : {\r\n              \"query\" : \"spring boot\",\r\n              \"fields\" : [ \"title^3\", \"rawContent\", \"author\" ],\r\n              \"fuzziness\" : 1,\r\n              \"minimum_should_match\" : \"30%\"\r\n            }\r\n          },\r\n          \"should\" : [ {\r\n            \"term\" : {\r\n              \"current\" : true\r\n            }\r\n          }, {\r\n            \"term\" : {\r\n              \"_type\" : \"projectpage\"\r\n            }\r\n          }, {\r\n            \"match\" : {\r\n              \"title\" : {\r\n                \"query\" : \"spring boot\",\r\n                \"type\" : \"phrase\",\r\n                \"boost\" : 3.0,\r\n                \"slop\" : 1\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          } ]\r\n        }\r\n      },\r\n      \"filter\" : {\r\n        \"or\" : {\r\n          \"filters\" : [ {\r\n            \"range\" : {\r\n              \"publishAt\" : {\r\n                \"from\" : null,\r\n                \"to\" : \"now/d\",\r\n                \"include_lower\" : true,\r\n                \"include_upper\" : true\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          }, {\r\n            \"not\" : {\r\n              \"filter\" : {\r\n                \"type\" : {\r\n                  \"value\" : \"blogpost\"\r\n                }\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          } ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"post_filter\" : {\r\n    \"or\" : {\r\n      \"filters\" : [ {\r\n        \"and\" : {\r\n          \"filters\" : [ {\r\n            \"terms\" : {\r\n              \"facetPaths\" : [ \"Projects/Api\", \"Projects/Reference\" ],\r\n              \"execution\" : \"or\"\r\n            }\r\n          }, {\r\n            \"terms\" : {\r\n              \"facetPaths\" : [ \"Projects/Reactor Project/1.1.0.RELEASE\" ],\r\n              \"execution\" : \"or\"\r\n            }\r\n          } ]\r\n        }\r\n      }, {\r\n        \"terms\" : {\r\n          \"facetPaths\" : [ \"Blog/Engineering\" ],\r\n          \"execution\" : \"or\"\r\n        }\r\n      } ]\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"sort\" : [ {\r\n    \"_score\" : { }\r\n  }, {\r\n    \"publishAt\" : {\r\n      \"order\" : \"desc\"\r\n    }\r\n  } ],\r\n  \"facets\" : {\r\n    \"facet_paths_result\" : {\r\n      \"terms\" : {\r\n        \"field\" : \"facetPaths\",\r\n        \"size\" : 100000,\r\n        \"order\" : \"term\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"highlight\" : {\r\n    \"order\" : \"score\",\r\n    \"require_field_match\" : false,\r\n    \"fields\" : {\r\n      \"rawContent\" : {\r\n        \"fragment_size\" : 300,\r\n        \"number_of_fragments\" : 1\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
    at sagan.search.support.SaganQueryBuildersTests.fullTextSearch(SaganQueryBuildersTests.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How should I fix this? (Java version I am using is 1.8.0_65)

Comment: You could execute gradle without running the tests: `./gradlew clean build -x test` (however, this is just temporary solution for the failing integration test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just pushed a fix for this - indeed, an integration test was platform-dependent: not stripping line return chars when comparing a string with something read from the file system.

In the future, don't hesitate to open issues [against the github project, even for questions](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/issues).

Comment: Well, it fixed that error. But I now get `org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found:`

Comment: did you clone the project using git? the project is trying to fetch the latest git SHA to make it available in the application at runtime. This error means that it can't find the git metadata locally.

Comment: No I didn't. I just downloaded the zip file and unpacked it. Just now I cloned it via github desktop. Then tried to build it. But it threw 6 exceptions on `DocsWebhookControllerTests`. All of them has `WebhookAuthenticationException: Could not verify signature`

Comment: I guess this is linked to https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/issues/619 - and probably another platform-dependent issue. I'll look into it. In the meantime, you can temporarily ignore tests.